# WPF UI not updating while using BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing `WPF` Client application that communicates with Server over `TCP/IP using sockets.`I have multiple WPF forms and I connect to the server as soon as the application loaded

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
        ShowMimic("CCRMain");
    }
}
```

I used `BackgroundWorker` to continuously updating UI by the data it received from Server. But unfortunately UI does not updated automatically, however when the form is reloaded e.g by switching back and forth between forms,the UI gets updated itself b/c of following load event

```
private void Mimic_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MyWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Please let me know, how my UI will automatically gets updated as soon as the application received data from server through sockets. `Data()`function does communication with server.

**C# WPF Client Application**

```
BackgroundWorker MyWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
int[] allRodPosition = new int[17];

public CCRMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyWorker.DoWork += MyWorker_DoWork;
    MyWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += MyWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
}

private delegate void UpdateMyDelegatedelegate(int i);
private void UpdateMyDelegateLabel(int i)
{
    //label1.Content = "BckgroundWork:" + i.ToString();
}
private void MyWorker_DoWork(object Sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateMyDelegatedelegate UpdateMyDelegate = new UpdateMyDelegatedelegate(UpdateMyDelegateLabel);
    DispatcherOperation op = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        Data();
        A1G1Text.Text = allRodPosition[0].ToString();
    }));
}
private void MyWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object Sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
}
void Data()
{
    MainWindow mw = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
    NetworkStream serverStream = mw.clientSocket.GetStream();
    byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(A1G1.Text + "$");
    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
    serverStream.Flush();

    byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
    serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)mw.clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);

    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(inStream);
    System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(ms);
    int[] inComingData = new int[17];

    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
    {
        inComingData[i] = br.ReadInt32();
        allRodPosition[i] = inComingData[i];
    }
}

private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
    MainWindow mw = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
    mw.ShowMimic("DemandPosition");
}

private void Button2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
    MainWindow mw = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
    mw.ShowMimic("LiftCoil");
}

private void Mimic_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

}

Comment: You have the answer to your question already in your question. When is your background worker being run according to your code? And when do you _want_ to run the background worker? (Hint: "_I used BackgroundWorker to continuously updating UI by the data it received from Server_". This is a false statement, according to the code in your question. You currently don't use the background worker this way...)

Comment: Then how can use BackgroundWorker to achieve the required result please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker;
    private Timer timer1;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _backgroundWorker.DoWork += backgroundWorker_DoWork;
        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        InitTimer();
    }

    public void InitTimer()
    {
        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Elapsed += Timer1OnElapsed;
        timer1.Interval = 2000; // in miliseconds
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void Timer1OnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            TxtToBeUpdated.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            CallSocket();
        });
    }

    private void CallSocket()
    {
        //do socket 
    }
}
```

try Dispatcher.Invoke to update UI thread after your socket call